trying to push git files but get this error "fatal: Invalid proxy URL 'https:/github.com': only SOCKS proxies support paths"
I tried this command:
git push -u origin main

but i get this error:
fatal: Invalid proxy URL 'https:/github.com': only SOCKS proxies support paths
fatal: remote helper 'https' aborted session

how can i fix this

Looks like it might have been a typo when you set up your origin remote -- your URL only has one / after https:.
Run git remote show origin. If the Fetch URL and/or Pull URL there also only has one slash, edit .git/config to add the missing /, and see if that fixes it.
